# Threejs collada 3D model not render properly for some angle

Tags: three.js, collada

I have used Collada model for one of my product 3D preview with canvas as texture and normally it's working fine but for some angles 3D corner part are not rendering proper.

I have attached screenshot of canvas and 3D modal along with DAE modal.

Is there issue with modal? please find Collada model [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lwzn8hpspw3ffos/AADX0X17aHA3pBap3k3Vw-_Aa?dl=0)

[image]
[image]

Please find my code below:

```js
width = 256, height = 256;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 1, width / height, 0.01, 300 );
camera.position.set( 8, 10, 8 );
camera.lookAt( 0, 3, 0 );
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager( function () {
  scene.add(collada.scene ); // while loading collada model i am updating scene and assign new collada.scene to it
});

loader = new ColladaLoader( loadingManager );
ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
scene.add( ambientLight );

spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
spotLight.target = scene;
spotLight.position.set(0, 0, 0);
spotLight.castShadow = !0;
spotLight.shadow && spotLight.shadow.mapSize.set(width, height);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in your Collada file although it is not necessarily responsible for the rendering artifacts. The problem is the following section:

```xml
<library_images>
  <image id="Map #3-image" name="Map #3"><init_from>file://D:\Mit\3D Box\57.15 x 57.15 x 152.4 overlay\57.15 x 57.15 x 152.4 Open\57.15 x 57.15 x 152.4 Front Open.png</init_from></image>
  <image id="Map #5-image" name="Map #5"><init_from>file://D:\Mit\3D Box\57.15 x 57.15 x 152.4 overlay\57.15 x 57.15 x 152.4 Open\57.15 x 57.15 x 152.4 Back Open.png</init_from></image>
  <image id="Map #6-image" name="Map #6"><init_from>file://D:\Mit\3D Box\57.15 x 57.15 x 152.4 overlay\57.15 x 57.15 x 152.4 Open\57.15 x 57.15 x 152.4 Border Open.png</init_from></image>
</library_images>
```

As you can see, it contain absolute file path targeting a file system. These definitions do not work if you load the Collada asset in a browser. Assuming the textures are located in the same directory it should be:

```xml
<library_images>
  <image id="Map #3-image" name="Map #3"><init_from>57.15 x 57.15 x 152.4 Front Open.png</init_from></image>
  <image id="Map #5-image" name="Map #5"><init_from>57.15 x 57.15 x 152.4 Back Open.png</init_from></image>
  <image id="Map #6-image" name="Map #6"><init_from>57.15 x 57.15 x 152.4 Border Open.png</init_from></image>
</library_images>
```

The geometry of the model itself seems to render fine when importing it in the [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/).

Comment: Hi @Mugen87, 
I am replacing texture mapping with canvas so it's not came into picture and in my final file I am using  relative path still for corner there were issue like added

Comment: Are you sure that your generated canvas actually maps to the texture coordinates of the Collada's geometry?

Comment: yes while I zoom out than only such issue come at without zoom render fine also for particular angle only not for all angle

Comment: Can you please try to set the `minFilter` property of your canvas texture to `THREE.LinearFilter`? This issue could be related to mipmapping.